# Can not access static class from .dll without namespace prefix

Tags: c#, namespaces, class-library

I have a class library project with definition like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {           
        public static string GetString()
        {                
             return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

When I reference the built .dll of this project in my another project/solution, I can access the class `MyClass` like `MyNamespace.MyClass.GetString()` but I can't access by referenceing the namespace on top of c# file. Ex.

```
using MyNamespace;
namespace ProjectNameSpace
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public void TestRun()
        {
            string result = MyClass.GetString(); // Getting error: are you missing an assembly reference?
        }
    }
}
```

It may be a silly question, but I am not getting why this is happening. Any help on this is really helpful to me.

Comment: Are you sure that you have two projects or something similar and have _not_ referenced the DLL in the second instance? Otherwise this shouldn't happen.

Comment: that shouldn't even compile anyway because of the `var`

Comment: I have updated the question code, this is just sample I posted, I have referenced dll for sure. As I mentioned I was able by MyNamespace.MyClass.GetString() this way but not by referencing on top of the file.

Comment: Rather than posting "sample code", please try to create a [mcve]. Since the first version obviously didn't compile, expecting that the current version *exhibits your actual problem* is a bit far fetched, unless you can tell us that you have *actually* placed these code samples in two projects (please state what type of projects) and compiled them and that they do exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* that the name of the namespace was different from the name of the class in the library? I have just run into a problem similar to this one, and after a few minutes of experimenting I realised that was the problem.
[Here's an image showing the existance of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BCQ6.png) Note that testLib is in references and is also using'd.

Here's the code of the library

```
namespace testLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Object getMe()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
    public static class Class2
    {
        public static int getRandomNumber()
        {
            return 7;
        }
    }
    public class testLib
    {
        public static void testMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("working just fine...");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code of the tester class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using testLib;

namespace libTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Class2.getRandomNumber());
            testLib.testLib.testMe();
            testLib.testMe();//when i hover here, it says "The type or namespace does not exist in the namespace testLib (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```